# HTTPS redirects get lost through tunneling

Tags: java, ssl, nginx, jakarta-ee

I experience a problem while doing integration tests of our system, that usage of a JSF application via https always returns a 400 (forbidden) when coming back from a redirect after POST because of conversion to http. This only happens, if the request is done through a tunneled connection via jumphost.

So here's the setup:

- Server has a WildFly running with an JSF application and an nginx which cares about incoming https requests from 443 and transfer them to the WildFly port
- Server is in a closed network which is accessable via a jumphost which again can be accessed from my machine
- An SSH connection establishes a tunnel between a local port on my machine and the 443 port on the server
- The browser requests https://localhost:myport

Now, whenever I post something, e.g. the login, the redirected answer comes back with http scheme and thus gives me a 400. If I manually add https in the browser, the requests gets answered correctly.

A curl of the same URL gives me this:

```
curl -i -k https://localhost:8426
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 15:03:52 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: INCENTCONTROL_JSESSIONID=[....]; path=/
Location: http://localhost:8426/login.xhtml
```

If I do the very same directly from a machine within the network of the server, everything is fine.

What has the tunneling to do with the problem and does anyone have an idea how to overcome it?

Comment: I could imagine that the problem is because the domain expected by the server application is not the domain you use, because you are tunneling. The domain you use shows up in the TLS handshake and also as Host header and thus can have effects on the server behavior. This is also likely the reason you need to use `-k`, i.e. ignore certificate problems caused by this. Instead you should make curl use the real name but with the tunnel IP address. See the `--resolve` argument of curl for this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the hint, sounds reasonable.